# Stop Permission Inheritance >> set unique permission .. is this possible using PnP Core SDK

Tags: sharepoint-online, development, pnp

Can we perform the following actions using PnP Core SDK @ https://pnp.github.io/pnpcore/?

1. Access the permission of a folder

[image]

[image]

2. Stop Permission inheritance

[image]

3. Set unique permission

[image]

please i do not want to share the folder using links >> i want to use the exact above steps? are those possible? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use **BreakRoleInheritance** method of **ListItemAllFields** property.
In my code snippet "Test Library" is the document library title and "Test Folder" the name of the target subfolder.

```
using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope()) 
{
    // Ask an IPnPContextFactory from the host
    var pnpContextFactory = scope.ServiceProvider.GetRequiredService<IPnPContextFactory>();

    // Create a PnPContext
    using (var context = await pnpContextFactory.CreateAsync(new Uri(siteUrl)))
    {
        // Get Root Folder
        var rootFolder = (await context.Web.Lists.GetByTitleAsync("Test Library", p => p.RootFolder)).RootFolder;

        // Ensure SubFolder
        var subFolder = await rootFolder.EnsureFolderAsync("TestFolder");

        // Break Inheritance on SubFolder [BreakRoleInheritance(bool copyRoleAssignments, bool clearSubscopes)]
        subFolder.ListItemAllFields.BreakRoleInheritance(false, true);

        // Get current user
        var currentUser = await context.Web.GetCurrentUserAsync();

        // Find role definition
        var roleDefinitions = (await context.Web.GetAsync(p => p.RoleDefinitions)).RoleDefinitions;
        var editRole = roleDefinitions.AsRequested().FirstOrDefault(p => p.Name == "Edit");

        // Add role to selected user
        await subFolder.ListItemAllFields.AddRoleDefinitionAsync(currentUser.Id, editRole);
    }
}
```

Comment: your code worked well for me .. thanks a lot